# Onsubmit normal behaviour?

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

Okay so based on how I understood it when you attach `onsubmit` to a form the code that is set will be run.  So in essense the following code:

```
function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('saveForm').onSubmit = saveTodo();
    }

window.onload = init;
```

Should trigger the saveTodo - function.  However I was under the impression that this is done **only when the form is submitted**. Here's the saveTodo - function:

```
function saveTodo() {
    'use strict';

    console.log('saveTodo()');
    return false;

}
```

Yet when  I refresh the browser this function is called even though no form submission has been clicked.

Is this normal behaviour for onsubmit?

Here's the html form:

```
<form id="saveForm" name="saveForm">
      <div>
         <label for="todo">Give a task:</label>
         <input type="text" name="todo" id="todo" />
      </div>
      <div>
         <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Add" />
      </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: can you post the entire code you're using on a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('saveForm').onSubmit = saveTodo;`

Answer (score 0):

Ah it seems the problem was a stupid typo.  Instead of using `onSubmit` the syntax was `onsubmit`.  So the following code worked:

```
function init() {
    'use strict';

    document.getElementById('saveForm').onsubmit = saveTodo;
    }
```

Thanks for **`rps`** for noticing the parentheses.

Comment: Actually the parentheses are likely to be the important part.  `saveTodo` refers to/returns the method of that name.  `saveTodo()` **executes** that method, and returns the result.  Hence the logging during `init()` - and the element's onsubmit would be set to `false`.

Comment: happens, sometimes when one is stuck with such issues, fresh pair of eyes is always helpful, glad to lend you mine!